# Allow postback using if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

Is it possible to only allow postback from  a
button click when an if statement is true?
Whenever the postback occurs from the else part of the statement it resets the lblPrice to 100

```
lblPrice.Text ="100"
int biggerPrice =500;       

    if (txb1.Text != "0" )
    {
     lblPrice.Text = biggerPrice.ToString();
    else{
     lblErr.Text = "Woops!";
    }
```

Comment: Anything is possible. Why do you want to do that? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It seems you are talking about validation. I think this will be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use @html.action in a razor view which can utilise if / else blocks. It will call an mvc controller to manipulate your strings.

Comparing your values in the view is tricky. You would need to either put values in viewdata every page refresh or a static state class
(Dont do this; code smell).

Comment: I don't think it's an MVC website, rather asp.net

Comment: an mvc website is a design structure within the asp.net framework. The original poster has not specified against it.

Comment: lblErr.Text in an MVC website?